# CSS doesn't work when I add slash (/) at the end of my url

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, view, controller

I'm new to code igniter and I wonder why my css doesn't work when I add slash ( / ) at the end of the url ..

Can someone help me why it doesn't work ? And help me make it work ?

Comment: we should see your css first

Comment: I am guessing you are including the css with an relative url and the slash is treated as a new level of "fake directory" so the relative url is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this add code to your html `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('css/style.css');?>" type="text/css"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has method: site_url() - which generates your home url with '/' (slash) at the end.

To access public assets of your application
use this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>public/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>public/js/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Note: `href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>public/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css"`